Unit test subdivs with bUnit
I am trying to test a blazor component. In the logic of the component i set some text in an subdiv somewhere inside the component. Now i want to verify that the text is set properly:
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Title
    </div>
</div>

At the moment i use the following code to instantiate the component. Now i want to verify that "title" is actually used as the title.
[Fact]
public void TestSomething()
{
    // act
    var cut = RenderComponent<MyComponent>(parameters => parameters
        .Add(p => p.Title, "title")
    );
}

Now how would i verify that "title" is actually rendered in the right place?
I found two approaches: either i build an system to generate unique ids throughout my whole project or i just set static ids. Both are either way to much work or end in duplicate ids. Are there any better approaches to test something like this?

There are several different approaches available to you. Read all about it in the docs: https://bunit.dev/docs/verification/verify-markup.html

All the approaches verify the whole markup. But i only want to verify that the data is in it's destined tag, i don't care about the remaining markup

cut.Find("div > div:nth-child(2)").MarkupMatches("<div>title</div>");

Ok thanks, i've started testing using a somewhat similar approach (adding some unique attributes to the tags i want to access). Are there any obvious disadvantages i didn't think of in my approach?

Just that you have that extra noise in you markup with the test attributes. Generally, I recommend the testing-library.com philosophy. We are working on supporting all testing-library apis in bUnit too via the bunit.web.query package.

Figured it out myself: i just use a custom data attribute, e.g. data-id-abcd
I can reference this in bUnit using the following CSS selector: [data-id-abcd].
For every tag i want to access i create a custom attribute with some random 4-digit hex id. Using this technique i can identify tags without having some duplicate ids. Further it keeps the code pretty clean and maintainable as it only adds a hand full of attributes to every component.

There is another way if you are not willing to add id's or classes.
The CSS specification introduced a bunch of pseudo selectors, one of them is the contains selector.
So you could do something like this to make your test somewhat work:
[Fact]
public void ShouldRenderDiv()
{
    var cut = Render<MyComponent>(ps => ps.Add(p => p.Title, "Foo"));

    var theDiv = cut.Find("""div > div:contains("Foo")""");

    theDiv.TextContent.Should().Be("Foo");
}

Now, the downside of this approach is that your test is tightly coupled to the markup of your component under test.
